# How can I get +ruby feature in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: linux-ubuntu

Really I'm just looking for `vim` compiled with `+ruby` and when I installed `vim.gtk3` it doesn't come compiled with it instead on `:version` it comes up as `-ruby`.

I'd like to use the [vim-readability](https://github.com/pondrejk/vim-readability) plugin, but it has a dependency on `ruby` and a ruby-library called `odyssey` so vim needs ruby integration to use it.

Comment: @Quasímodo No, actually I can’t seem to install ‘vim-gtk’ on a Ubuntu 20.04 live usb. (I was able to install ‘vim-gtk3’)

Comment: @Quasímodo Correct.

Comment: Darn yeah...unless someone else has something like a PPA.

Comment: @Quasímodo Never heard of it; I’ll take a look at it; I can compile stuff, but on a live usb? :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

- Install [`vim-nox`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/vim-nox). From the package description (`apt-cache show vim-nox`),

  ```
  This package contains a version of vim compiled with support for
  scripting with Lua, Perl, Python 3, Ruby, and Tcl but no GUI.
  ```
- Install [`vim-athena`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/vim-athena). From the package description (`apt-cache show vim-athena`),

  ```
  This package contains a version of vim compiled with a Athena GUI
  and support for scripting with Lua, Perl, Python 3, Ruby, and Tcl.
  ```